# Creating Dataframes in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to create a dataframe from a list

Can someone let me know why I'm getting the error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.

with the following

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
test_list = ['green', 'peter']

df = spark.createDataFrame(test_list,StringType()).toDF("color", "name")
```

Thanks

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test_list` should contain the list of rows where the rows should be a tuple or list like

`test_list = [('green', 'peter')]`
or
`test_list = [['green', 'peter']]`

In case more than one rows it will be like

```
test_list = [('green', 'peter'), ('red', 'brialle')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(test_list, schema=["color", "name"])
df.show()
```

Results in

> +-----+------+
> |color| name   |
> +-----+--------+
> |green|peter   |
> +-----+--------+
> |red  |brialle |
> +-----+--------+

Reference: [CreateDataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame)

Comment: thanks for reaching out. Following on from your answer, can you let me know why the followingw won't work ```people = spark.createDataFrame(list(['green','peter'])) ,IntegerType().toDF("color", "name")``` I get the error 
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: BTW, I just tried both of your suggestions, and neither of them worked. I'm getting the same error message "The number of columns doesn&#39;t match."

Comment: Can you or someone assist further?

Answer (score 0):

```
required_columns = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_numbers', 'courses']

target_column_names = ['user_id', 'user_first_name', 'user_last_name', 'user_email', 'user_phone_numbers', 'enrolled_courses']

users_df. \
    select(required_columns). \
    toDF(*target_column_names). \
    show()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).